# MongoDB ReferenceError: Collection is not defined :

Tags: mongodb, collections, reference

Why does MongoDB not allow me to copy one collection into another?

```
> db.crashntsb.copyTo(crashntsbclean)
2017-01-13T09:09:49.236+0530 E QUERY    [main] ReferenceError: crashntsbclean        
is not defined :

@(shell):1:1
>
```

It says the new collection is not defined What could be the reason?
Do I need to create the collection?
In the documentation it says Mongodb creates this new collection
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following code will work for you.

```
db.crashntsb.copyTo("crashntsbclean")
```

The double quotes is required although the documentation does not say so.